# None of subtitle editors show video

Tags: lubuntu, video, codecs, subtitle

I'm on lubuntu 15.04. I've installed `Subtitle compose`, `Gnome subtitles` and `Subtitle editor`, however, none of them show my .avi file. I've tried executing `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`, but nothing changed. In `Subtitle editor` I get this error:

> GStreamer plugins missing. The playback of this movie requires the
>   following decoders which are not installed:
>
> XVID MPEG-4 decoder

I've also installed `libxvidcore-dev` and `libxvidcore4`.

The video itself plays fine. All subtitle editors are fine with audio.

EDIT: 64-bit OS

Comment: It is the same in Ubuntu-Studio-64, and it is also complaining about missing the x264 decoder. I seem to recall it working in the early 14.04 or some, but after upgrade it stoped working, I was hoping to see it come to life again with a new clean install of 15.04, but alas no!!  Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This is five years after the fact, but it seems this question still ranks highly in Google searches of this problem, so I'll mention what just worked for me in a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

I want to note that this Ubuntu came with VLC already installed, and that I don't have `h264enc` nor `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` nor `libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0` installed: `apt list --installed` + grep does not show them, as I only have the `good`, `bad` and `ugly` gstreamer plugins. Installing the libav package alone solved SubtitleEditor's complaints about the H.264 and MPEG-4 decoders.